# cant write qr code (phpqrcode) in /var/www/html/phpqroce/temp

Tags: php, chmod, chown, ownership

I already set `sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/phpqrcode`
and also `/temp data`
but still the `phpqrcode` won't write image qr to `/temp` directory.

Need help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my php5 is missing some module called php gd2

to install php gd2 simply:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

and restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

it works. dont forget to `sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/phpqrcode`